# Getting "Access Denied" on Chrome/Firefox when using Selenium Chrome WebDriver on IRS Website

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, access-denied

When I try to access a specific webpage on the IRS website using the automated program I've wrote in Java (using Selenium ) with ChromeDriver or the Firfox one, I get a "Access Denied" on the webpage.
The problem only occurrs when using the automation, but not if I try to enter the page regulalrly in a browser.
[enter image description here][1]
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

This is the Headers from Selenium where error occurred::authority:

```
content-length: 321
content-type: text/html
date: Thu, 14 Jul 2022 10:08:54 GMT
expires: Thu, 14 Jul 2022 10:08:54 GMT
mime-version: 1.0
set-cookie: akaalb_sa_alb=1657794234~op=ALB_SA_FATCA:SA_Origin_DCS|~rv=56~m=SA_Origin_DCS:0|~os=850f67b9c612bad1bf84b6b3a1b0f61e~id=cc6cfd6fc0883aae00c44b84b3e2cf47; path=/; Expires=Thu, 14 Jul 2022 10:23:54 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None; Domain=.sa.www4.irs.gov
set-cookie: _abck=36476E779F8DD441FE6CF51F811292DB~-1~YAAQj3UZuD0eitSBAQAA1ssu/AjeqTafuJcMGZxTsBZzonnKcU8IwWH4z7frShTx5O3w/yMFfrBSdMdSM5SWmCxnXgYodEvAhkg4BpuKyI7uwnCNnPwBs2q+unE/mUKbS+QlGxFFLgrjwocEfOhaEHavNwMIHIDdZ3gKsCFkj8+0kvmAZxjlCsDuEm2MCyuLm4OchiUfKGozPMNGbg10lBkG1JPRoLu7p5x9jzIgZhODj9EypZ74D8sEMZ3+6SDmLjhpwpAHq88AF2JXYvfTFmOWbYMqecaIVdhQorZKO9gQsO/kGhxXQeLk4B0NSurjNq0HbOeMrPDC1oKwCdg+WafUtLQDgvk+NiyaJPmZhKhM3tyU7Y85Lqskgy/XWK3kUkRaSFJRBw==~-1~-1~-1; Domain=.irs.gov; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 14 Jul 2023 10:08:54 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Secure
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-reference-error: 18.8f7519b8.1657793334.138094ab

sa.www4.irs.gov
:method: POST
:path: /fatca-rup/reg/login/userLogin.do
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 544
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygRgYyBa2MA85XueA
cookie: JSESSIONID=-aL3-28OXp0G1VTOONXmvnhF.1d; dc=dcs; bm_sz=E1E3453EC7DA460F8376F180E28B1CD2~YAAQj3UZuDAeitSBAQAA96Uu/BCMnG98SroeBWcIpBX7zxbIipZ+0Bo2cZl2ZTKunkdDBZ7MFXOmnen4chIqCA5RFiADu5Fm27Xuh7gJ9IJvCBRzqcSf2gQpE/ZSqkehmKDJh7qhs3pUXcuxreeZa7nvVlDap0oCKtek2wB6zIYzLHJfigBvb0RPip+83c8/mFQMeNa7QewhdcF+/5Diqs0AWT3tlKwMssQURh11bxeVdQrWPEdfiXjHFzUPeHH6PoUh+UlAwP+4SyZUbUQAavCDgq53uyNNPDlLnQpKkKw=~3293508~3354937; ak_bmsc=9A8D055FEB2045327234CCBB1B1FE4FA~000000000000000000000000000000~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; akaalb_sa_alb=1657794227~op=ALB_SA_FATCA:SA_Origin_DCS|~rv=56~m=SA_Origin_DCS:0|~os=850f67b9c612bad1bf84b6b3a1b0f61e~id=2b2c7641b2572ff1e0543b187da2fbdd; _abck=36476E779F8DD441FE6CF51F811292DB~-1~YAAQj3UZuDseitSBAQAAz78u/Ai+NwP0Qos+v3QUvft78P3j38N3oz3JMadXI2Z1ukr1NVl+lLxNW7SBSrBsudkC8LcGKxLnH0nDEHOcdOoPzfSf0TJwHYRi6IZZWRzwM+6PDII3LTFak3AieJDr93P3a8mbg/LffnltmLxF2sOK3i0EKPKNJYCU893NlKWeghKDmu7glyezVN2E0GZaiyMrtfQR5OGWfdurl+Eji6Y5P53u5CUvvEekrObKm5wRyu3UGEyGeauCmW21Ts6usM4ztr0gg4yS+M7SE/74lXCVuBcQV0Be7HJMe3ACujAoyeCh70hVsrkytrcIPgP17p9vYhzM2D1zrOn5ldrl9VnBzKDkgearqh+WUiPfZmK4HQI9IDs2lg==~-1~-1~-1
origin: https://sa.www4.irs.gov
referer: https://sa.www4.irs.gov/fatca-rup/reg/login/userLogin.do
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36




Here is from the Browser where it enters the correct url:



content-language: en-US
content-length: 0
date: Thu, 14 Jul 2022 08:31:36 GMT
location: https://sa.www4.irs.gov/fatca-rup/reg/warningBanner.do
set-cookie: dc=dcd; Path=/; Version=1; Secure; Httponly; Max-Age=900
set-cookie: akaalb_sa_alb=1657788396~op=ALB_SA_FATCA:SA_Origin_DCD|~rv=3~m=SA_Origin_DCD:0|~os=850f67b9c612bad1bf84b6b3a1b0f61e~id=2ecaf248633b35c6d1414676505d2018; path=/; Expires=Thu, 14 Jul 2022 08:46:36 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None; Domain=.sa.www4.irs.gov
set-cookie: _abck=50CE16507D3C6AA33720F57830103CA8~0~YAAQnXUZuGBSw/uBAQAAI7jV+wisjW1+Q9TBJXsfWoLsHgcAY/6v881t40IDMNgv4/wK5sIZRJll9JWvzCK1Xo4eJQE6850nI7Y03/cNXJo4uWTNsSDMCTTfJF7RTxtOrLBxAosLZxAGrOK5h4PWhGMFAJXpTk643rMoXyX7YwSs11vvzspyzlXWunfVA4LD3g/M23T36BPsEPoHlfXIu6n1Q9DkDY20Gpk5VCIFbWrdta6Ci+FSyUpZh4AD+CfJIg5kmumvlATzvyQbSxtYUiEnQlgzqBSuUBo4bUYD4cFGh6TXCInmzInTe7RXAST/yGvMRUeXddTsbMeh0SCxrmhuZJ1PTnpWvKTlp+usNTzPc7A7iypCp0CXW7ltQ986egxk+Sr8~-1~-1~-1; Domain=.irs.gov; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 14 Jul 2023 08:31:36 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Secure
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

:authority: sa.www4.irs.gov
:method: POST
:path: /fatca-rup/reg/login/userLogin.do
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 544
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9RcKiEsy9ZX0iaZB
cookie: JSESSIONID=wOS3NJHrJLXyd7RQVAfOJsq4.1d; _4c_=%7B%22_4c_mc_%22%3A%226da06553-3591-4bb3-87f3-150e5aa46264%22%7D; _ga=GA1.2.2040318868.1656496493; _ga_ZY6FM95CS5=GS1.1.1656496493.1.0.1656496496.0; bm_sz=77EA66EB4D7DEE5594F812A41660EAE6~YAAQj3UZuBf/idSBAQAATf+z+xAIBs3R4EwZvXWCnZzblFdM34x/9GeMfpMzU1D1JfNfO4RKyCAza3glFYJ4upQ3rZWpChph4ePIrGn6A5QG1seUt5KoiWhZUTwXryMBuIrEQWwhh3cmITR44xTwIiCY20vQxJkwC5SXgAbroAmaXANc6XBFri8HlZeckKxBkBrGvYo28S0Eg4OaC4xABtJth3iFU/tYlvc/LxkGxgG/lBXlMfiyBVcs3UWovqNbOFMfVps7+2vIl2njs8if8inhxW2jN9RYoUvxVWDLqwU=~3229234~4473401; dc=dcd; akaalb_sa_alb=1657788394~op=ALB_SA_FATCA:SA_Origin_DCD|~rv=3~m=SA_Origin_DCD:0|~os=850f67b9c612bad1bf84b6b3a1b0f61e~id=8ab9c9b1749652dccbff787413f95fec; _abck=50CE16507D3C6AA33720F57830103CA8~0~YAAQnXUZuF1Sw/uBAQAAQ7DV+whrUeA+LUGglv3X23m6Tw2yZKvAKYoJukR8053o8kYN9IRVJHGTt1Dp4b5ZqeNnmwhhoZ2U+elGrpKybPvXvmpkXL3K3fQdP+TG1Qpy+OsNoPVHMIZWDQIAeOexBBIe6q1DRn8uxxZzlgPQO6e6P5N8EppK7E71Yshuu04YZNGRSmfgP8MI54rHdCVY1KHPg8lncsWOAEdiXcGzOxW57ksphaCbAHGAniGs3oUX2McLeOEgbLnldCyDxmUd80ehQHHEZE3kMEEEonVTVjXo8bIu/kb1D6VyazF/fKNm+GBAhLOiCpcKd5/ckEP6CZBCaoKwUccxcZ29cqZRWVSEKCqQG2uf4qRmFA==~-1~-1~-1; ak_bmsc=462E9E317ED85C5E346A54971080898E~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQnXUZuF5Sw/uBAQAAQ7DV+xAMztq/DIS+bAhW9ggBsdxBiw7zKSeF36NuJtdkveKfkCpbt/l8krfpCBICi6CYzeYf7BAhad018KYgQsTdjukoWdHAg22yKr+1ktrVTlm/73cLTzvV2NgAM7e0bbcenKDGIQlQ3GGy3ZJPwYsoL/1BDHbuuBvMF6P+CSjJbddHQDXfRR35VqB22ElUjzl4CG3jMeyA8ydTH9+8pe2ab0ODRng2z1OieY6LREqUIhEsw0nakOJ7BhtLLqirEE/v3OJiYCsofC5vEEICmmaCnDEbPrc9vmBM+iuGSm8wElE9XuPyXj2O+5Fpi6pEViADwjjypj/wpjpmnxq5Sc1ud3ErD0O4VlJUR6zGvzN56JCcjD+YwJRYag==
origin: https://sa.www4.irs.gov
referer: https://sa.www4.irs.gov/fatca-rup/reg/login/userLogin.do
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: What happens when you open the page regularly, but in an "incognito tab"?

Comment: It enters to the page with no problems.

Comment: I've also tried to use the --no-proxy Chrome Option but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you referring to this website? https://www.irs.gov

Comment: This: https://sa.www4.irs.gov/fatca-rup/reg/login/userLogin.do    , and when checking the checkbox and clicking the Create Account

Comment: Any update anyone?

Comment: What you could do in order to get an understanding about what is happening is to compare the request headers that are being sent in both cases. Open the Dev-Tools, and then copy the headers from the network tab.

Comment: headers added to original message

Comment: any update anyone?